# Is it true that electronics such as laptop computers are tax free in Cambodia?

Tags: electronic-items, shopping, cambodia, taxes

I've heard or read that electronics, computers etc do not carry any tax in Cambodia, making it a very cheap place to purchase such things.

I'm in Cambodia now but in a small village and with almost no money left before I can go home. But since my netbook is dying I would make a stop in Phnom Penh to buy a replacement on a credit card.

But I'm having trouble finding out if this is true, a bit of a myth, or something in between. Such as maybe it's technically true but prices don't end up being that low for other reasons?

(I'm not looking for often-faked stuff such as Apple and I don't have the option of buying in the US where prices and risk are both very low.)

Answer (score 1):

That's true. But I don't think Cambodia is a good place to buy electronics stuffs because the cheap fakes of famous electronics brands such as Nokia, Sony can often be found there.

Comment: I don't want famous brands such as Nokia or Sony or Apple. I'd be surprised if they have fake low-end notebook computers like Asus, Lenovo, Samsung.

Comment: @hippietrail By what definition of “low-end” is Lenovo low-end?

Comment: @gerrit: Similar specs to a "netbook". But maybe I don't know anything about Lenovo (-:

Comment: I do not share the belief that no one would counterfeit low-end computers. One of the most longest-lived counterfeiters in USA history made only low-quality $1 bills, because no one paid them much mind. (h/t, my dad, who told me this story two generations ago!) http://www.snopes.com/business/money/mister880.asp